# Multiple $_POST Values for One Form Object

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a webpage that displays two images that have associated buttons. When one button is clicked, I want the page (once the button is clicked, the page is reloaded and posts to itself) to increment the wins field of the image whose button was clicked, and increment the loses field of the image whose button was not clicked. This requires knowing the name of **both** images, but only one button is posting its data, so only one piece of information can be transferred to the next page.

I haven't been successful in finding a method by which a single form object (a button in my case) can post multiple values as is required for my program. Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<input type="hidden">` will let you send you multiple values, whichever button was clicked.